# php code hosted in godaddy uploads large file to AWS S3, however site gets hanged after uploading 60+MB file

Tags: php, file-upload, amazon-s3

my site is hosted in godaddy cpanel (shred hosting) and we use AWS S3 for storing files. I am able to upload files upto 45-50 MB without any issue. However, when I try uploading file that is 65 MB+, it gets loaded in S3 but site is hanged at that point. It doesnt do the next tasks after upload; just shows round circle as in it is still uploading file.

I have tried setting below values in php.ini file - `post_max_size = 200M`, `upload_max_filesize = 200M`, `max_execution_time = 1800`.

This doesnt work. Please help.

Comment: try setting this too max_input_time = 1800

Comment: Issue was due to limited I/O in godaddy shared hosting. It was fixed once we moved the site to EC2.